# How can I let-bind a variable to input read with `completing-read`?

Tags: variables, let-binding, completing-read

How can I store the selected value in a `let` variable when using `completing-read` ?

```
(let ( (selc '("Lower-Skeleton" "Upper-Skeleton")) )
  (completing-read "Vista: " selc nil t "Upper-Skeleton")
```

Comment: The question isn't clear. There's no `let` in the question, other than in the title. And it's unclear what you mean by a "selected value".

Comment: `completing-read` will direct the user to make a selection.  The user selection will then be used at a later stage, so I need to store the selected value.

Comment: Tag [`selection`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selection) is about selecting text (e.g. an active region).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `setq` just like with any other variable:

```el
   (let (foo)
       (setq foo (completing-read ....))
       ;; do something with `foo'
       ...
   )
```

`foo`'s scope is limited to the body of the `let` form: it's a local variable. Other than that, it's just like any other variable.